# Django URL design for posting update to a model instance

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Say I have the following model defined:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And there's an existing Location instance with `id=1`

I want to post an update against this instance but I am not sure how I should send the pk/id to the server. I have two ideas in mind.

1. Include it as part of the url (ex. `^update_location/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'`).
2. Include it in the POST data along with values for updating other attributes.

My question is why would I want to choose one over the other?

I am leaning more towards option 1 because it's supported, by default, by the generic view `django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView` that I am using. But then I still don't know how to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you can do like this:

```
url(r'^update_location/(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', 'location.views.update'),
```

and then in your view:

```
def detail(request, location_id):
    // do whatever needed with location_id object
    location = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
    return HttpResponse("You're updating location %s." % location_id)
```

and about the form handling you can have a look at :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs

Comment: Ok. But why this one over the other approach? Any problem with the other approach?

Comment: I would say this approach (django style) produces cleaner urls... Apart from that I don't see anything wrong. The classic POST way has been working for ages :)

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 makes python easier because reverse() will make urls just fine.

Option 2 makes javascript easier because it won't have to make up the url and POST data.